# Segmentation Error in Function/Struct/Pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, file-io, struct

I am trying to read in two images and then output them into two multidimensional arrays and then later in the program flip/blend/output the images. Does anyone have any ideas why I continue to get a segmentation error? I know it's within the `ReadImages` call beacuse it complies and then when I execute it -- the first call comes up, but fails after that....

```
void ReadImages(struct ImageType *imgur, struct ImageType *imgur2)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char filename[30];
    char filename2[30];

    //Scanning in the first file.
    FILE *inputfile;
    fprintf(stdout, "Please enter the filename/location of the first image\n");
    fscanf(stdin, "%c", &filename);
    inputfile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(inputfile = NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Sorry you didn't specify correctly\n");
    }

    fscanf(inputfile,"%[^\n]%c", imgur->ppImage, &imgur->newlinechar);
    fscanf(inputfile,"%[^\n]%c", imgur->comment, &imgur->newlinechar);
    fscanf(inputfile,"%i %i", &imgur->width, &imgur->height);
    fscanf(inputfile,"%i", &imgur->maxColor);

    for(i = imgur->height - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for(j = 0; j > imgur->width; j++)
        {
            fscanf(inputfile,"%i", &imgur->image[i][j].red);
            fscanf(inputfile,"%i", &imgur->image[i][j].green);
            fscanf(inputfile,"%i", &imgur->image[i][j].blue);
        }
    }

    //Scanning in the second file.
    FILE *inputfile2;
    fprintf(stdout, "Please enter the filename/location of the second image\n");
    fscanf(stdin, "%c", filename2);
    inputfile2 = fopen(filename2, "r");
    if(inputfile2 = NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"Sorry you didn't specify the filename/location correctly\n");
    }

    fscanf(inputfile2, "%[^\n]%c", imgur2->ppImage, &imgur2->newlinechar);
    fscanf(inputfile2, "%[^\n]%c", imgur2->comment, &imgur2->newlinechar);
    fscanf(inputfile2, "%i %i", &imgur2->width, &imgur2->height);
    fscanf(inputfile2, "%i", &imgur2->maxColor);

    for(i = imgur2->height - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for(j = 0; j > imgur->width; j++)
        {
            fscanf(inputfile2,"%i", &imgur2->image[i][j].red);
            fscanf(inputfile2,"%i", &imgur2->image[i][j].green);
            fscanf(inputfile2,"%i", &imgur2->image[i][j].blue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(inputfile2 = NULL)` is a logic error.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey is right - you need `==` since you are in effect setting the file pointer to NULL (so when you use it you will crash).

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
fscanf(stdin, "%c", &filename);
```

to read in the filename, but `%c` is the format specifier for a single character. You want `%s`, for a string, instead. The `&` in front of `filename` is also unnecessary.

The same thing applies for:

```
fscanf(stdin, "%c", filename2);
```

Comment: @sjs wow... It's always the little things that trip me up... Thanks so much!

Comment: @Floris - The expression `&filename` here does not dereference `filename`, it does not access the _string "contents"_. The only difference the `&` makes is the expression's type - `filename` were of type `char *`, `&filename` of type `char (*)[30]`.